# how to loop over each changeInfo['changeInfo'][1...x]['Url']

Tags: python

I have the following code snippet ,i want to change it in such a way where I want loop over for each changeInfo['changeInfo'][1..x],how can I do that

```
  for changeInfo in MainchangeInfo:
    if (changeInfo['CRStatus'] == 'Fix' and (('Not Provided' in changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['Url'] or 'Wrong change Provided' in changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['Url']) or 'NEW' in changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['Status'] or 'ABANDONED' in changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['Status'] or 'Yes' not in changeInfo['RNotesStatus'] or 'Provided' not in changeInfo['RCAInfo'] or 'False' in str(changeInfo['IsDevComplete']))):
      if 'Wrong change Provided' in changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['Url'] or changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['Info'] != 'Available' ://want to loop over for changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]
        changeMailBody = changeMailBody + "<tr bgcolor=\"Red\">"
```

Comment: First of all Welcome to Stackoverflow.Second,provide more description of the problem and the needed solution,so that we can help you.

Comment: @Andy - currently above codesnippet is checking for changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['Info'] and based on the value  colorcoding is set to Red,I want to check for each changeInfo['changeInfo'][x]['Info']  value and if its not 'Available" then only set to Red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by `[1..x]`?

if you want to loop over the 'first x' elements in `changeInfo['changeInfo']` (in which case, did you mean `[0..x]`?) you can use slice notation:

```
for item in changeInfo['changeInfo'][:x]:
    # do stuff
```

if you really want from 1 to x, i.e. skipping the first element you can do:

```
for item in changeInfo['changeInfo'][1:x]:
    # do stuff
```

See docs here:
http://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

EDIT:

After your clarification in the comment it's clear you don't even need slice notation, you just need `for item in changeInfo['changeInfo']` ...I think your full example would look like:

```
for changeInfo in MainchangeInfo:
    for item in changeInfo['changeInfo']:
        if (changeInfo['CRStatus'] == 'Fix' and (('Not Provided' in item['Url'] or 'Wrong change Provided' in item['Url']) or 'NEW' in item['Status'] or 'ABANDONED' in item['Status'] or 'Yes' not in changeInfo['RNotesStatus'] or 'Provided' not in changeInfo['RCAInfo'] or 'False' in str(changeInfo['IsDevComplete']))):
            if 'Wrong change Provided' in item['Url'] or item['Info'] != 'Available' ://want to loop over for changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]
                changeMailBody = changeMailBody + "<tr bgcolor=\"Red\">"
```

Comment: basically i want to lo0p over all the changeInfo['changeInfo'][1..x]['Info'] meaning,changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['Info'],changeInfo['changeInfo'][1]['Info'],changeInfo['changeInfo'][2]['Info']... i dont know the limit ,dont know the value of x...how do do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an explicit loop:

```
for change in changeInfo['changeInfo']:
    info = change['info']
    # do stuff with it
```

Or, if you want to write it out as a comprehension:

```
infos = [change['info'] for change in changeInfo['changeInfo']]
```

Or, if you just want an iterator, not a list:

```
infos = (change['info'] for change in changeInfo['changeInfo'])
```

In any case, you will get `changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['info']`, then `changeInfo['changeInfo'][1]['info']`, and so on.

---

I'm assuming here that `changeInfo['changeInfo']` is a list, not a dict whose keys happen to be small integers. If that assumption is wrong, just replace `changeInfo['changeInfo']` with `changeInfo['changeInfo'].values()` in whichever solution you choose. (Of course in that case, the order will be arbitrary, but that's exactly what you should expect from a `dict`.)

---

So, in your existing code, instead of this:

```
  if ('Wrong change Provided' in changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['Url'] or
      changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]['Info'] != 'Available'):
```

… I'd use the generator expression, together with the [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function, like this:

```
  if any('Wrong change Provided' in change['Url'] or change['Info'] != 'Available'
         for change in changeInfo['changeInfo']):
```

Now instead of checking whether this condition is true for the *first* value in `changeInfo['changeInfo']`—that is, `changeInfo['changeInfo'][0]`—you're testing whether it's true for *any* of the values in `changeInfo['changeInfo']`. Which, as I understand it, is exactly what you wanted.